# How to save a changed item to an external file? (Python 3)

Tags: python, save, external

I'm fairly new to python, but I'm making a script and I want one of the functions to update a variable from another file. It works, but when I exit the script and reload it, the changes aren't there anymore. For example (this isn't my script):

```
#File: changeFile.txt
number = 0

#File: changerFile.py
def changeNumber():
    number += 1
```

If I retrieve *number* during that session, it will return 1, but if I exit out and go back in again and retrieve *number* without calling changeNumber, it returns 0.

How can I get the script to actually save the number edited in changeNumber to changeFile.txt? As I said, I'm fairly new to python, but I've looked just about everywhere on the Internet and couldn't really find an answer that worked.

EDIT: Sorry, I forgot to include that in the actual script, there are other values.

So I want to change number and have it save without deleting the other 10 values stored in that file.

Comment: And what exactly have you tried? Googling "python save file" brings up thousands of hits for me...

Comment: i didn't find any open function.

Comment: Make a txt file and use it like a database. Write the file with your variable and read it file from your another script. There you go.

Comment: Matt: I said it in the OP, none of them really had an answer. Raj: This is just a very basic example. I've messed around with open() as a solution but I couldn't find anything that really worked. howaboutNO: see reply to Alex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming, as you show, that `changeFile.txt` has no other content whatever, then just change the function to:

```
def changeNumber():
    global number  # will not possibly work w/o this, the way you posted!
    number += 1
    with open('changeFile.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write('number = {}\n'.format(number))
```

ADDED: the OP edited the Q to mention (originally omitted!-) the crucial fact that `changefile.txt` has other lines that need to be preserved as well as the one that needs to be changed.

That, of course, changes everything -- but, Python can cope!-)

Just add `import fileinput` at the start of this module, and change the last two lines of the above snippet (starting with `with`) to:

```
for line in fileinput.input(['changefile.txt'], inplace=True):
    if line.startswith('number ');
        line = 'number = {}\n'.format(number)'
    print line,
```

This is the Python 2 solution (the OP didn't bother to tell us if using Py2 or Py3, a crucial bit of info -- hey, who cares about making it **easy** rather than **very hard** for willing volunteers to *help* you, right?!-).  If Python 3, change the last statement from `print line,` to

```
    print(line, end='')
```

to get exactly the same desired effect.

Comment: One part of my file checks the value, and if it's 0, it does one thing, and if it's 1, it does another. To get it to run correctly, I had to already include number in changeFile. Wouldn't this create a second value for number then?

Comment: Also, I looked into flush() upon hearing it updated files from the buffer, but all it did was completely wipe clean the file. (Hence the name apparently lol) The file only had 10 or so lines in it so it was only a minor inconvenience.

Comment: @TomT, the code I show rewrites `changeFile.txt` from scratch, which is why I clearly spelled out it will work only if "`changeFile.txt` has no other content whatever"!-)  If it **does** have other content to be preserved, edit your Q to clearly specify **that**, and I'll show you how to use the standard library's `fileinput` module to address the issue!-)

Comment: Once again, I'm sorry, I'm on my phone now, but I'll add my Python version to the OP. I'll try this tomorrow, thanks! :)

Comment: @TomT, I gave you solutions for both Py2 and Py3, what else appears to be a problem?!

Comment: I didn't say there was another problem, just saying my computer is inaccessible atm. It's like 10:30 where I am and it's been a long day, so I'm in bed right now typing this from my phone.